# I get very random results when running the function GetVolumeInformation()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems

I wanted to obtain the type of filesystem of a particular drive (FAT32, NTFS, FAT16) for a program that i am writing. But when i run this code, I get seemingly random results in the `szFileSystemName` variable. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{
   TCHAR szFileSystemName[10]; 
   ::GetVolumeInformation(L"C:\\", NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
   szFileSystemName, sizeof (szFileSystemName));

   cout << szFileSystemName; 
   cin.get(); 
}
```

Thanks,

Samuel

Comment: Have you checked the return value of the function? It can fail, and you can get more information why using [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).

Comment: if instead `cout << szFileSystemName` you look under debugger value of `szFileSystemName` or `MessageBoxW(0, szFileSystemName, szFileSystemName, 0)` ? i already not say about check result of api call

Comment: When running the function GetLastError() it returns false (0)

Comment: @RbMm Thankyou, I see where the error is.. I ran it and printed it using a message box and it worked.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(szFileSystemName)` gives you the number of **bytes** (or `char`s) in the object, **not** the number of `TCHAR`s. A `TCHAR` is 2 bytes wide, so you are providing a number that is 2x what it should be (... probably, [depending on compiler settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings#tchars)). Since you set the size of the array, you know it is `10`.

Comment: I actually don't use Windows, so I'm not totally familiar with the fun with character types they have, but... what is shown if you use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout`?

Comment: Calling `GetLastError` unconditionally is wrong. You must first check the return value of the function.

Comment: Using `L"C:\\"`, an explicitly `L` prefixed wide-character string, with `TCHAR` is wrong; it's supposed to use the `_T` or `_TEXT` macro. But I strongly suggest you abandon `TCHAR` to use only Unicode and call `GetVolumeInformationW`. (And to whoever deleted my last comment, I will keep adding it unless you bother to explain yourself. That's rude, uncivilized behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cout << szFileSystemName;`

Above line print the `szFileSystemName` array address. So it is different every time.

To print the file system name you can use:

`wprintf(L"File system name: %s \n", szFileSystemName);`

or

`std::wcout << szFileSystemName;` @Remy Lebeau pointed out.

Comment: Or, just use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout`, if `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t` instead of `char` (ie, if `UNICODE` is defined during compiling)